# Save Javascript file object to local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a input type file where I save the file to a file object like so

```
var uploadControl = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
var files = uploadControl.files[0];
```

Then I would like to save that file to local storage to read into the FileReader object at a later time. Does anyone know if this is possible. I have tried several different options and every time I try and retrieve the object out of local storage, it is undefined.

Here are some things I have tried

```
var setObj = {"prop": "myProp", "file": files};
chrome.storage.sync.set({"myObj":setObj});
```

This doesn't throw errors, but when I try and retrieve the object, it is undefined

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("myObj", function(item) {
console.log("item name: " + item.myObj.file.name);
});
```

However I can access the other properties of the object

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("myObj", function(item) {
    console.log("item prop: " + item.myObj.prop);
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong when adding the object to local storage or am I accessing it incorrectly? Or is it just impossible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` can only contain string name/value pairs, which means you can not store an object directly.You can use [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for that.

Comment: simply json serialize the object. :)

Comment: Guess I missed the key/value pair part of the local storage documentation. Thanks! That solves my problems.

Comment: Actually, that did solve my problem in terms of saving the object, but once I parse it, I am still unable to read it. I am guessing the file path information is removed when the object is converted to JSON. Has anyone successfully saved a file object and then read it later with the FileReader interface?